# Can a function call a callback or return a promise automatically under the correct circunstances?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have been working with JS for some relevant time and after reading lots and lots of stuff regarding callbacks, promises and now the acclaimed async/await (that is actually a more elegant way to use promises IMHO) so I was wondering if an async function could handle both callback calls and returning promises given certain conditions.

I was thinking about a function ***kinda*** like this

```
function division (dividend, divisor, callback) {
    if (divisor === 0) {
        const err = new Error('Can not divide by zero')
        if (callback) callback(err, null)
        else return new Promise.reject(err)
    } else {
        if (callback) callback(null, (dividend/divisor))
        else return new Promise.resolve(dividend/divisor)
    }
}
```

then it could be called in both ways

```
division(10, 2, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.log('Ops!')
    else console.log(result)
})
```

or

```
division(10, 2)
.then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Would this **idea** work somehow?

*If somehow works*, it would be a good idea to implement functions in this style?

*If somehow works and it would be a good idea*, it could be improved?

Thanks in advance! I really like to study language mechanisms, it is a nice way to improve your own standard thinking towards anything.

Comment: It's totally possible. But I don't think it's a good idea. Ideally there is only one way an API works. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: It should work but I'd rather stick with 1 approach to keep consistency. (And hopefully one day callbacks will only belong to the past lol). If you do go that way I would suggest checking `typeof callback` to make sure it's a function, you don't want to try to call a third random parameter.

Comment: Your idea works but your promise example wouldn't. This could be a solution if you wanted to upgrade an old API but I would rather use a `promisifying` function/module for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Google APIs are implemented like this. For example here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.10.x/Zone#get

> If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.